Cannot Return A Value From Iterator C#
I am attempting to return an Enumerable value with an asynchronous function.
I'm having a problem converting the returned data type value to the "main" method, because there is an asynchronous call made within it. I keep implementing the changes recommended and what I read online, but everytime I make a change Visual Studio doesn't like something else I've done, and then I have to go back.
The error is on the "ListOfLambdas" function. Specifically, it is on the "yield return" line. The Error number is [CS0029][1]
What are you looking to do?
I'm looking to capture a list/iterable value that I can then pass around and do other work on.
public void FunctionHandler()
{


    IAsyncEnumerable<AWSLambda> returnedListOfLambdas = ListOfLambdas();
}

private async IAsyncEnumerable<AWSLambda> ListOfLambdas()
{
    //Instantiating Client:
    var lambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient();
    //Instantiating New Lambda List:
    List<AWSLambda> list = null;
    //Getting List
    var response = await lambdaClient.ListFunctionsAsync();
    response.Functions.ForEach(function =>
    {
        AWSLambda aWSLambda = MapLambda(function);
        if(list == null)
        {
            list = new List<AWSLambda>();
        }
        list.Add(aWSLambda);
    });
    yield return list; //Here is our error.
}



private static AWSLambda MapLambda(FunctionConfiguration function)
{
    AWSLambda lambdaToBeAdded = new AWSLambda();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionName = function.FunctionName.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionARN = function.FunctionArn.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionDescription = function.FunctionName.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionRunTime = function.Runtime.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionMemorySize = function.MemorySize.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionTimeout = function.Timeout.ToString();
    lambdaToBeAdded.FunctionHandler = function.Handler.ToString();
    return lambdaToBeAdded;
}

The error that I am getting is specifically, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<saveFileS3.AWSLambda> to 'saveFileS3.AWSLambda'
But this seems strange to me. I think it is rather clear that the 'list' variable is not that data type. What am I missing?
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029)

The error number on its own is useless. Always include the complete, exact error message.

Bit weird to return a IAsyncEnumerable when the list itself is not async. Probably best to just do private async IEnumerable<AWSLambda> ListOfLambdas() and then return response.Functions.Select(MapLambda).ToList();

@KenWhite You must have responded pretty quickly. If you review the message, you'll notice I edited the post to include that.

List<AWSLambda> list = null; is exactly System.Collections.Generic.List<saveFileS3.AWSLambda>, hence why the compiler is complaining when you're trying to return AWSLambda.
You need a foreach with a nested yield return:
foreach (var lambda in list)
    yield return lambda;


Ideally, you'd rewrite as such:
private async IAsyncEnumerable<AWSLambda> ListOfLambdas()
{
    using (var lambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient())
    {
        var response = await lambdaClient.ListFunctionsAsync();
        foreach (var function in response.Functions)
        {
            yield return MapLambda(function);
        }
    }
}

Note that AmazonLambdaClient implements IDisposable so it should be disposed when you're finished with it.

Don't return the list. You don't need a list. Instead, yield return the items that would have gone into a list, one at a time.
response.Functions.ForEach(function =>
{
    yield return MapLambda(function);
});

